# WPF ButtonStyle and MouseEnter/-Leave-Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseenter

I have a Style-Template for my buttons in my app, that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Name="Border">
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffff" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffff" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffff" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffffff" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now I wanted to put a MouseEnter and a MouseLeave Event in some of my buttons and change their background, etc. on the fly. If I disable the Style, everything works fine as expected (except, that the buttons get the border and the blue background of the standard style).
Now my question would be: "How can I change the style to a borderless, transparent button without blue background on MouseOver and get the MouseEnter and MouseLeave to fire, so I can set the background programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

you should add extra styles for the buttons that you want to react differently than the rest, then use the triggers like in your pasted code to change backgrounds.

```
<Style x:Key="diffrentButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

...

Comment: Sounds good, but the problem is, that the buttonbackgrounds are polygons that are created on the fly. So I cant use XAML-triggers... I wanted to use programmatically changes. These polygons are beneath (ZIndex -1) the buttons and are transparent like the buttons. When theres an mouseenter they shall get a specific color. how i said, it already works without styletemplates... nearly....